# What's the canonical way to create a date from three numbers representing days, months and years?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a year 2009, a month 11 and a day 12. All of these are being passed to me as integers. What I want to do is create a date from these. I want to use these as part of my where statement.

What is the best way to do it from either a clean code and most importantly a speed point of view?

I personally am using MS SQL, which I'm sure will make a difference.

Thanks in advance,

Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `INT`s are called `@d`, `@m` and `@y`:

```
DATEADD(month, ((@y - 1900) * 12) + @m - 1, @d - 1)
```

**EDIT**

Please note that this technique isn't "canonical" in any way, it relies on manipulating SQL Server's implementation of `DATETIME`.

If you pass invalid values for `@d`, `@m` or `@y` then you'll get an invalid `DATETIME` in return:

- { @y=2009, @m=11, @d=12 } returns 2009-11-12 (correct)
- { @y=2009, @m=11, @d=50 } returns 2009-12-19 (wrong)
- { @y=2009, @m=13, @d=12 } returns 2010-01-12 (wrong)

Comment: This will only work if the dates in the differnt fields are actually valid dates when combined together. This is why it is a bad idea to store date informatin that way.

Answer (score 5):

The most unambiguous formats, using only integers, are `YYYYMMDD`, `YYYY-MM-DD`, and `YYYY/MM/DD`.  I can't speak to MSSQL specifically, but in my experience, `YYYY-MM-DD` is the most universally supported (due in no small part to it being part of the [ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

Comment: the latter is more common because it's an ISO standard (ISO 8601)

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question as it doesn't account for what you are supposed to do to convert the integers into the date format.

Comment: You didn't state what language your integers were being "passed" in. From the accepted answer, I take it you're working with a stored procedure, but I didn't know that at the time. :-)

Comment: Sorry Ben, didn't mean to appear rude. You are absolutely correct. I didn't phrase my question unambiguously. I ammended the question to add, "to use these as part of my where statement". Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about combining them to store in a database or you have them stored that way and want to combine them in a query and convert to a dte to use date math functions?

Comment: I want to use them as part of a where statement.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ben yyyy-mm-dd (the ANSI standard) is a pretty safe bet, as its not as ambiguous as dd mm yyyy or mm dd yyyy. SQL Server will happily convert a varchar passed in that format to a date.